# how to find telegram channel messages count using telegram API

Tags: api, telegram

I want to get a message's views but I don't know which method should I use.
[Here](https://core.telegram.org/methods) is the telegram API. I have the channel ID and the message_id,(I got them from my telegram bot). I know that telegram bot API doesn't have access to views so I want to use the main telegram API but I don't know which method should I use.

Comment: You can't acquire this data from bot

Comment: `message_id` value is count

Comment: NO. `message_id`'s value isn't count

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: @alihossein nodejs

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this steps:

- create a post link (https://t.me/channel_username/post_id)

example: https://t.me/tehrandb/93

- open the link with PHP or Python or other languages

[image: exammple]

- Extract the field value with the ‍‍`tgme_widget_message_views` class

Comment: Is this sustainable on the longer run?

Answer (score 1):

by python and telethon you can access to a certain message
and that message object have an attribute 'view':

```
m = Message(id=4864, to_id=PeerUser(user_id=818906659), date=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 4, 47, 57, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message=':reminder_ribbon:تک فیلم آموزش پروژه محور \n:man:\u200d:computer:پیاده سازی  Responsive Menu \n:point_left: 0 تا 100\n:round_pushpin:با css & html\n#web\n@stepbysteplearn', out=False, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, from_id=818906659, fwd_from=MessageFwdHeader(date=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 20, 29, 53, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), from_id=None, from_name=None, channel_id=1023032463, channel_post=11711, post_author=None, saved_from_peer=PeerChannel(channel_id=1023032463), saved_from_msg_id=11711), via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, media=MessageMediaDocument(document=Document(id=5803386688260540004, access_hash=5193338638774407914, file_reference=b'\x01\x00\x00\x13\x00]\x18l:\xb7\xd5\r&\xe8\xb5j\xa65*\xea\x01\xdc\xe2Py', date=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 20, 29, 52, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), mime_type='video/mp4', size=16955767, dc_id=4, attributes=[DocumentAttributeVideo(duration=668, w=1280, h=720, round_message=False, supports_streaming=True), DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name='Responsive_Menu_With_Media_Queries.mp4')], thumbs=[PhotoStrippedSize(type='i', bytes=b'\x01\x16(\xc5\xa2\x8a(\x00\xa2\x8a(\x00\xa2\x8a(\x00\xa2\x8a(\x00\xa2\x8a(\x00\xa2\x8a(\x03'), PhotoSize(type='m', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=455132553, local_id=24511), w=320, h=180, size=644)]), ttl_seconds=None), reply_markup=None, entities=[MessageEntityHashtag(offset=90, length=4), MessageEntityMention(offset=95, length=16)], views=6276, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None)
```

`m.views` will return a specific message views

full information of a message object in telegram.